# How to run mongo shell commands in Node.js Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to run the `isMaster()` command within my node.js project. The problem is that I'm unsure how to run any sort of mongo shell command via js code.

I know in Python you can use `client.admin.command('ismaster')`.

If this isn't achievable within mongoose, I  am open to using the mongodb package, but I'd like to keep it solely mongoose. I am just trying to test if a connection is within a primary node.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be looking at driver documentation, in this case the node driver docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`Db.executeDbAdminCommand`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Db.html#executeDbAdminCommand) or [`Db.admin().command`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Admin.html#command).

This is how you would run it with mongoose:

```
mongoose.connection.db.admin().command({ isMaster: 1 }, (err, result) => {
  console.log('Result: ', result);
})
```

or

```
mongoose.connection.executeDbAdminCommand({ isMaster: 1 }, (err, result) => {
  console.log('Result: ', result);
})
```

Comment: how to run rs.status() ?